# Wrong datatype detection for csv files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract the datatype of dataframe cell using below scripts:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path,sep= '|',dtype=object)
d = {"<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>": 'date',
     "<class 'int'>": 'int',
     "<class 'float'>": 'float',
     "<class 'str'>": 'str'}
df1 = df.applymap(type).astype(str).replace(d)
```

But this is working fine with XLSX files but not able to detect the datatype of CSV files.

for CSV files, it detecting every cell as str but correctly detect the datatype of excel files.

df screenshot:

```
index   A    B     C 
0      ws    1.7   1
1      rd    1     nan
```

df1 output:

```
index    A    B    C    D
0       str   str  str  str
1       str   str  str  float
```

Can anyone suggest to me any suggestion/solution for it?

Comment: You are using `dtype=object`, why did you expect anything else?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i am reading it as object so that blank will not convert datatype of cell

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove `dtype='object'` or can specify the datatype for each column separately:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,sep= '|',dtype={'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32, 'c': 'Int64'})
```

This will read your columns from csv in the specified formats.

Comment: basically i am reading the with dtype as object so that it will not convert the data type of other cell.

Comment: `dtype=object` will convert all columns to `object`. Its better to specify separate `dtypes` for separate columns.

Comment: the above script is working fine for xlsx files but we are getting issue for csv files using the same logic

Comment: Basically i want generalise the things  as files are changing each and everytime